# Why can't I get the my fetchedResults in init?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI View struct to which I pass a *Place* object in the init function. Using an *id* I want to load a corresponding *UserPlaceInfo* from CoreData.
Unfortunately my app crashes when I try to access the fetchedResults in the init function. 
If I use the same code in onAppear this works without problems.

```
private var fetchRequest : FetchRequest <UserPlaceInfo>
private var fetchedResults: FetchedResults<UserPlaceInfo> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }

init(place : Place) {
    self.place = place
    fetchRequest = FetchRequest<UserPlaceInfo>(entity : UserPlaceInfo.entity(), sortDescriptors : [] , predicate: NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", place.id))
    // Application crashes here!
    let count = fetchedResults.count
}
```

Why is that and what can I do about it?
Am I doing something wrong or are the fetchedResults not yet available at this time?
I need the result very early, because if there is no UserPlaceInfo in CoreData, I have to create such an object.

UPDATE

Adding *fetchRequest.update()* helped a bit. Now I am getting a more useful error message: *Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator*

I still don't understand what is going on. I add the managedObjectContext to the environment in the SceneDelegate and the fetch works fine if I do it in onAppear.

Comment: Try to use `fetchRequest.update()` before fetchedResults usage

Comment: which error message is displayed in the crashlog?

Comment: Is this MacOS or iOS? The last error looks like the issue with the persistent store coordinator not being loaded yet on MacOS. Removing `lazy` for `var persistentContainer` in the AppDelegate or making sure it gets initialised before the ContentView is created is a solution.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It is iOS but still in the simulator. Removing lazy did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this same issue, you've probably gotten it to work by now, but I figured I'd help someone out if they encounter this in the future. You won't have access to the managedObjectContext in init. Instead, what you'll want to do is create a separate method and call that on appear. Modify your code like so.

```
init(place : Place) {
    self.place = place
    fetchRequest = FetchRequest<UserPlaceInfo>(entity : UserPlaceInfo.entity(), sortDescriptors : [] , predicate: NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", place.id))
}
```

And then in your body, you do something like this

```
var body: some View {        
  VStack {
    .. your views here
  }.onAppear(perform: onLoad) // the magic!        
}
```

And finally

```
func onLoad() 
{
    print(fetchedResults.count) // it should work now
}
```

Comment: I also used onAppear and it works fine. But I still wonder if there is another way.

Comment: In SwiftUI 1.0 there is no way to do it. Hopefully they address this in the next version